# iOS completion handler on geocodeAddressString(String:) not executing statements

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Currently making an app in which a view controller takes in the `addressString` and then geocodes the address to retrieve the latitude and longitude of said address as seen below inside of a `@objc` method.

```
@objc func addLocationTouchUpInside() {
        
        let addressString = "\(streetAddressField.text!), \(cityField.text!), \(stateField.text!)"
        var location = Location(id: Location.setid(), locationName: nil, addressString: addressString, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, HoHid: nil)
        // This geocoder instance is a let property initialized with the class
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location.addressString) { placemark, error in // Completion handler starts here...
            print("WHY")
            
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(error!)")
            }
            if let placemark = placemark?[0] {
                if let addresslocation = placemark.location {
                    location.latitude = addresslocation.coordinate.latitude
                    location.longitude = addresslocation.coordinate.longitude
                }
            }
            print("3: \(location.latitude)")
        }
        do {
            
            try AppDatabase.shared.dbwriter.write({ db in
                try location.insert(db)
            })
            
            self.currentUser?.locationid = location.id
            
            try AppDatabase.shared.dbwriter.write({ db in
                
                if var user = try User.fetchOne(db, key: self.currentUser?.id) {
                    
                    user = self.currentUser!
                    try user.update(db)
                    
                }
            })
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
        
        let locationInputViewController = LocationInputViewController()
        
        locationInputViewController.setUser(user: self.currentUser!) 
        locationInputViewController.setLocation(location: location)
        locationInputViewController.setHoH() 
        
        if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
           navigationController.pushViewController(locationInputViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is that any code within the completion handler (of type `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler`) does not seem to execute. Originally I had assumed that location simply wasnt being mutated for some reason. I then learned that nothing within the completion handler executes.

This question may seem like a duplicate to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094269/geocodeaddressstring-not-working-for-swift) however it seems a clear answer was not quite found. Via some comments on said post I had set both set a custom location for the simulator and used my personal iphone and saw no difference.

EDIT: I have updated the question with the entire function as requested in the comments. Second the completion handler I have been referring to would be that of `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler`. Defined as

`typealias CLGeocodeCompletionHandler = ([CLPlacemark]?, Error?) -> Void`

where

`func geocodeAddressString(_ addressString: String, completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)`

in the documentation. I have also commented the line where the completion handler starts.

Finally in only ONE of my runs was this strange error outputted:

`#NullIsland Received a latitude or longitude from getLocationForBundleID that was exactly zero`

Comment: Are you testing in a device or in a simulator?

Comment: Have you tried holding a reference to `geocoder` on your class? I don't know for sure, but my guess is that `geocoder` is being deallocated after your function scope exits. If you do this, I would also put `[weak self]` on the callback.

Comment: @matt I have used both. @Kubee If by holding a reference you mean making `geocoder` a `let` property on the view controller class, I just tried it with no different result. Also self is not referenced with in the closure, so I took `[weak self]` out.

Comment: "The issue I am having is that any code within the completion handler (of type CLGeocodeCompletionHandler) does not seem to execute"  Where is your completion handler?

Comment: I don't see any completion handler in the code you posted, can you post the entire function?

Comment: @ElTomato and Tadreik I have posted updates that hopefully answers your questions.